# Nested XML XSL for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble reading out my nested for-each loops. For some reason, it doesn't loop under the direct nodes. The trouble seems to be with the tages.My first loop happens after I open the table, and I loop through the whole table for the admin reports and nest the second node underneath it. This works fine, but when I go to nest additional nodes underneath, I am able to pull the values, but not specific to the parent node. My eyes are pretty much bloodshot from this exercise, could someone lend some help. Thanks in advance.

XSL:

```
    <tr bgcolor="9acd32">
    <table><th>Data Source Name:</th></table>
    <table><th><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>   </th></table>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
   <xsl:for-each select="*[name()='PartInformation']">  
       <table bgcolor="#99ff66"><th>Part Information:</th></table>
       <table bgcolor="#99ff66"><th><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></th></table>       
   <tr> 
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*[name()='InspPrgInformation']">    
       <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th>Inspection Program ID:</th></table>
       <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></th></table>
    <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th><xsl:value-of select="@NoOfTracefields"/></th></table>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>         
<tr> 
   <xsl:for-each select="*/*/*[name()='AreaInformation']">    
       <table bgcolor="#FFFF99"><th>Area Information:</th></table>
       <table bgcolor="#FFFF99"><th><xsl:value-of select="@Area"/></th></table>
       <table bgcolor="#FFFF99"><th><xsl:value-ofselect="@AreaCount"/>         
  </th></table>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>

 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</center>
```

XML:

```
 <AdminReports xmlns="30/11/2011 09:25:58">

  <AdminReport ID="1">
    <DataSourceInformation DataSourceID="2" Value="DCS_AERO_KINSTON_DCS350">
      <PartInformation PartID="8" Value="WithAreaInfo">
        <InspPrgInformation InspPrgID="10" Value="DCS350_Sec15Drill_Pannel1WithInfo"       NoOfTracefields="1">          
          <AreaInformation Area="L3" AreaCount="59"/>
          <AreaInformation Area="L4" AreaCount="45"/>
          <AreaInformation Area="LT4" AreaCount="54"/>
        </InspPrgInformation>
      </PartInformation>
      <PartInformation PartID="9" Value="NoAreaInfo">
        <InspPrgInformation InspPrgID="9" Value="DCS350_Sec15Trim_Pannel1" NoOfTracefields="0"/>
      </PartInformation>
    </DataSourceInformation>
  </AdminReport>

  <AdminReport ID="2">
    <DataSourceInformation DataSourceID="2" Value="DCS_AERO_KINSTON_DCS350">
      <PartInformation PartID="8" Value="NoAreaInfo">
        <InspPrgInformation InspPrgID="10" Value="WithInfo" NoOfTracefields="1">          

        </InspPrgInformation>
      </PartInformation>
      <PartInformation PartID="9" Value="AreaInfo">
        <InspPrgInformation InspPrgID="9" Value="DCS350_Sec15Trim_Pannel1" NoOfTracefields="0">
          <AreaInformation Area="L4" AreaCount="75"/>
          <AreaInformation Area="LT4" AreaCount="4"/>
        </InspPrgInformation>
      </PartInformation>
    </DataSourceInformation>
  </AdminReport>
</AdminReports>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is **wrong** for what you want to achieve:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[name()='PartInformation']">  
   <table bgcolor="#99ff66"><th>Part Information:</th></table>
   <table bgcolor="#99ff66"><th><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></th></table>       
   <tr> 
   <xsl:for-each select="*/*[name()='InspPrgInformation']">    
       <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th>Inspection Program ID:</th></table>
       <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></th></table>
    <table bgcolor="#33ccff"><th><xsl:value-of select="@NoOfTracefields"/></th></table>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The second for each is by no means related with the first one. Same goes with your third for-each.

Do not the the `current()` will give you the currently iterated node.

You could rewrite your first two for-each like this :

```
<tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[name()='PartInformation']">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current()/*/InspPrgInformation">
                        <table bgcolor="#33ccff">
                            <th>Inspection Program ID:</th>
                        </table>
                        <table bgcolor="#33ccff">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                            </th>
                        </table>
                        <table bgcolor="#33ccff">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@NoOfTracefields"/>
                            </th>
                        </table>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
```

The third one can be used with your current design. Because `current()` is local to each for-each, so your third for-each has no idea about the other two. In addition your design seems to be using xslt as a programming language which is not the way to go.

Finally try to provide some complete/compilable examples next time as well as your target document.